# Saving the users username to the firebase database using swift in Xcode

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created the user using email and password with firebase authentication, this is all working fine, however, now I want to save the users username to the database. This is what I've got for saving the username to the database...

```
var databaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference! {
        return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }

    let userInfo = ["email": user!.email, "username": self.usernameTextField.text, "uid": user!.uid]

                    // create user reference

                    let userRef = self.databaseRef.child("users").child(user!.uid)

                    // Save the user info in the Database

                    userRef.setValue(userInfo)
```

however the last line is giving the error "cannot convert type '[String:String?]' to an expected argument type 'AnyObject?'"

Does anyone know how I can fix this and get the username saved in the database? Thanks

Comment: Try downcasting the userInfo: `userRef.setValue(userInfo as! [String:String])`

Comment: thanks, just tried it then and its giving the same error. In the firebase documentation it says to use this 'self.ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["username": username])' however this isnt working either